# What is the maximum level for nested objects in Node.js?

Tags: node.js

What is the maximum nested depth for objects in the modern Node.js - version 4.x and later?

```
{a: {b: {c: {d: {e: {}}}}}}
```

I have implemented an algorithm that can resolve deep nested objects, which starts failing somewhere between 4 and 5 million levels, showing this:

```
<--- Last few GCs --->

   22269 ms: Scavenge 1474.2 (1532.4) -> 1474.2 (1532.4) MB, 2.0 / 0 ms (+ 1.0 ms in 1 steps since last GC) [allocation failure] [incremental marking delaying mark-sweep].
   22818 ms: Mark-sweep 1474.2 (1532.4) -> 1474.2 (1532.4) MB, 549.2 / 0 ms (+ 1.0 ms in 1 steps since start of marking, biggest step 1.0 ms) [last resort gc].
   23365 ms: Mark-sweep 1474.2 (1532.4) -> 1474.2 (1532.4) MB, 547.7 / 0 ms [last resort gc].


<--- JS stacktrace --->

==== JS stack trace =========================================

Security context: 0000021BC90373A9 <JS Object>
    1: split(aka split) [native string.js:~420] [pc=00000130CB0F8AE4] (this=000000DFECA04101 <Very long string[38888893]>,ay=0000021BC9004EB1 <String[1]: .>,az=0000021BC9004131 <undefined>)
    2: arguments adaptor frame: 1->2
    3: getIfHas [..\lib\utils\index.js:165] [pc=00000130CB137703] (this=0000006F2C894621 <an Object with map 0000015A54F5B6B1>,obj=...

FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - process out of memory
```

Is there any official figure I can reference that says `One shall not go deeper than...`?

It is the figure that I'd like to use in some edge-case tests, and refer to in documentation.

Comment: As Raymond Chen (and many others) have said, ["If you have to ask, you’re probably doing something wrong"](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20070301-00/?p=27803)

Comment: @AlexTaylor This is for edge-case testing. What's wrong with that?

Comment: What's the nesting level of `a` in `a = []; a.push(a)` ?

Comment: `var a = {}; a.a = a;` Maximum depth = Infinity?

Comment: @vitaly-t See the "Nitpicker's" note at the end of the previously linked article. It's going to change depending on the implementation you're using, which could change between runtime and OS versions, and the content you're putting into the structures (see Patrick Roberts' example).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no limit in the Javascript specification.

And since an embedded object is just a reference to another object that itself stands on its own, there's likely no coded limit other than some overall memory or object limitation.  Remember, that things aren't really nested the way they look in an object literal that is parsed by the interpreter.  Once an embedded object is parsed, it is its own object and the parent object only contains a reference to that object (it doesn't really contain the object itself).  You could assign the same "embedded" reference to many other variables too.  It's just an object reference.

It is also possible that there's a parser limit for an object literal declaration that is probably related to overall memory usage.  Again this would vary by implementation and cirumstances.

So, if you wanted to find a particular limit in a particular JS engine, you'd have to code a test and see if you could find a limit and running into a limit would probably not be related at all to nesting, but just to number of objects and memory used by them.

Comment: Doing some more tests, and it seems that the only limit is the memory available to the process, so this is a good answer!

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there is any restriction on nesting. Implementing such a restriction would probably be too expensive anyway. So my educated guess is that it's the same upper limit as the total number of symbols in a node.js process.